# Symfony 2: The option "validation_constraint" does not exist

Tags: forms, validation, symfony, symfony-2.3

I have a very simple form without class. I made some items with constraint options but the form validation does not work.
I've read several places ([e.g here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691804/symfony2-validation-form-without-class) )
I can add a `validation_constraint` parameter which is a `\Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Collection` instance.

When I try I always get an error message:

> The option "validation_constraint" does not exist. Known options are: ... blabla

My form:

```
$collectionConstraint = new \Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Collection(
            array(
                'customer' => new \Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank(),
                'customer_address' => new \Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank(),
                'customer_address_postal' => new \Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank(),
                'paymentDeadline' => new \Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Date(),
                'fulfillmentDate' => new \Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Date(),

                'currency' => new \Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Choice(array(
                    'choices' => $currency_entities
                )),

                'paymode' => new \Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Choice(array(
                    'choices' => $paymode_entities
                ))
            )
        );

$form = $this->createFormBuilder(null,array(
            'validation_constraint' => $collectionConstraint
            ))
            ->add('customer','choice',array(
                'choice_list'=> $customer_choices, 
                'multiple' => false,
                'required' => true,
                'empty_value' => '',
                'attr'   =>  array(
                    'class'   => 'chosen large',
                )
            ))
            ->add('customer_address','choice',array(
                'multiple' => false,
                'required' => true,
                'empty_value' => '',
                'attr'   =>  array(
                    'class'   => 'chosen large'
                )
            ))
            ->add('customer_address_postal','choice',array(
                'multiple' => false,
                'required' => true,
                'empty_value' => '',
                'attr'   =>  array(
                    'class'   => 'chosen large'
                )
            ))
            ->add('paymentDeadline','date',array(
                'input' => 'datetime',
                'widget' => 'single_text',
                'required' => true,
                'attr'   =>  array(
                    'class'   => 'date-picker m-ctrl-medium',
                    'addon' => 'icon-calendar',
                )
            ))
            ->add('fulfillmentDate','date',array(
                'input' => 'datetime',
                'widget' => 'single_text',
                'required' => true,
                'attr'   =>  array(
                    'class'   => 'date-picker m-ctrl-medium',
                    'addon' => 'icon-calendar',
                )
            ))
            ->add('currency','choice',array(
                'required' => true,
                'choice_list' => $curreny_choices
            ))
            ->add('paymode','choice',array(
                'required' => true,
                'choice_list' => $paymode_choices

            ))
            ->add('subject','text',array(
                'required' => false,
                'attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'span8'
                )
            ))
            ->add('comment','textarea',array(
                'required' => false,
                'attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'span8',
                    'rows' => 5
                )
            ))
        ;
```

Symfony version is 2.3.3.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Just for kicks, try changing 'validation_constraint' to 'constraints'.  Probably won't work but it might.

Comment: Thanks, I tried but nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The validation has to be applied to each field using the `constraints` option, not to the form builder.
So your code should be as follow:

```
use \Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;
use \Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Date;
use \Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Choice;

$form = $this->createFormBuilder(null)
            ->add('customer','choice',array(
                'choice_list'=> $customer_choices, 
                'multiple' => false,
                'required' => true,
                'empty_value' => '',
                'attr'   =>  array(
                    'class'   => 'chosen large',
                ),
                'constraints' => new NotBlank()
            ))
            ->add('customer_address','choice',array(
                'multiple' => false,
                'required' => true,
                'empty_value' => '',
                'attr'   =>  array(
                    'class'   => 'chosen large'
                ),
                'constraints' => new NotBlank()
            ))
            ->add('customer_address_postal','choice',array(
                'multiple' => false,
                'required' => true,
                'empty_value' => '',
                'attr'   =>  array(
                    'class'   => 'chosen large'
                ),
                'constraints' => new NotBlank()
            ))
            ->add('paymentDeadline','date',array(
                'input' => 'datetime',
                'widget' => 'single_text',
                'required' => true,
                'attr'   =>  array(
                    'class'   => 'date-picker m-ctrl-medium',
                    'addon' => 'icon-calendar',
                ),
                'constraints' => new Date()
            ))
            ->add('fulfillmentDate','date',array(
                'input' => 'datetime',
                'widget' => 'single_text',
                'required' => true,
                'attr'   =>  array(
                    'class'   => 'date-picker m-ctrl-medium',
                    'addon' => 'icon-calendar',
                ),
                'constraints' => new Date()
            ))
            ->add('currency','choice',array(
                'required' => true,
                'choice_list' => $curreny_choices,
                'constraints' => new Choice(array(
                    'choices' => $currency_entities
                )),
            ))
            ->add('paymode','choice',array(
                'required' => true,
                'choice_list' => $paymode_choices,
                'constraints' => new Choice(array(
                    'choices' => $paymode_entities
                ))

            ))
            ->add('subject','text',array(
                'required' => false,
                'attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'span8'
                )
            ))
            ->add('comment','textarea',array(
                'required' => false,
                'attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'span8',
                    'rows' => 5
                )
            ))
        ;
```

Note: I have added some `use` statements at the top to keep the code clear.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#adding-validation

Comment: Yes, I used constraints option but for some reason it did not work.
Therefore I separately from "FormType" to controller function as "form without type, class etc". Now it works.I do not understand. I think some deluded :) 

No problem, I'm happy :)

Comment: I have a doubt about my answer, can you try @Cerad suggestion: changing 'validation_constraint' to 'constraints' using your code?

Comment: Yes, I tried, but bothing. I tried with validation_groups, also nothing. 

Sorry, my previous comment is equivocal. Your advice is has helped!

Comment: Not sure why it is not working...but if the solution I provided is fine for you I will let it here.

Comment: I tried many things, and sure I lost it somewhere. I set everything back the way you suggested it and it works. Thanks again.

Comment: You might be a stupid question: can I use an model object that is not ORM Entity but it has the necessary property to a form?

Comment: You definitely can use a simple php class to pass to a form!

Comment: Yes, I tried with Assert annotations. When posted the form I wanted to get type (one property of the class) but nothing: no type no post data. I think it is because when form is completed (newAction()) said parameter is empty. It is a choice type but is empty and later loaded with data using ajax. 

I prefer to use such class to create a form because ORM Entity class sometimes tie my hands (may have different input).

This is a practical?

Comment: You probably should ask a new question containing the controller code and the class you have created. It is hard to see what is wrong without those information :)